# Print pdf to another pdf file from command line

Tags: command-line, pdf

I am trying to automate some jobs and one of them is pdf page sorting.

Until now, I have been using xreader and using print with pages range to sort a file and page setup to set 4 pages per side.

I came to an idea of using lp command to print one pdf file to another with certain parameters to print them in a specific order and with a setup of 4 pages per side. However, I am struggling how can I print to another file from a command line. Are there any solutions to the problem?

Comment: Read `man pdftk`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't manage to get expected results with your answers so in the end I have decided to use **pdfjam**.

```
pdfjam start.pdf '5,4,3,1,2' --nup 2x2 --scale 0.95 --outfile newfile.pdf
```

**--nup** puts 4 pages a sheet

**--scale** to add some margins to the page

**--outfile** path for new file

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do that with the **cat** command

Using the **>** option on the command line, like this:

```
cat source.pdf > destination.pdf
```

More information: man cat